# Can't change background color + can't use Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

I'm currently working on a little sculpture and when I want to change my background color nothing happens, same when I want to use cycles..

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're currently in the Material Preview/Lookdev mode? It uses EEVEE regardless of your choice of rendering engine, and has its own independent selection of backgrounds.

Comment: If that's not the case, would you mind sharing the .blend file?